# check date in range of 24 hours from now

Tags: php, datetime

I have been banging my head with this for a while now. Does someone know how I can check to see if `$theDate` is within the range of 24 hours FROM NOW.

This is the code I have come up with but it doesn't seem to work :(

```
if (time() <= ($theDate + 86400)) {
    // current time is 86400 (seconds in 24 hours) or less than stored time
}
```

**Note: `$theDate` is unix timestamp.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have it backwards:

```
if ($theDate <= (time() + 86400)) {
    // current time is 86400 (seconds in 24 hours) or less than stored time
}
```

Comment: Excellent, @FarhanAhmad! Please accept if you found useful :)

Comment: Will do as soon as SO lets me. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you always want the range to be 24 hours? Remember that there are sometimes 23 or 25 hours in a day when changing from/to DST.

A method that will take that into account is this:-

```
$tomorrow = (new \DateTime())->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
if((new \DateTime())->setTimestamp($theDate) < $tomorrow){
    //Do something
}
```

See the [DateTime manual](http://php.net/datetime) for more information on these very useful classes.

Comment: Actually I needed it to work within a range of 36 hours but I changed my question to say 24 because its more of a common question that someone else might be looking for. For the purpose of better SEO, etc.

So I was able to use @Ethans answer and simply change the number of seconds to my requirements.